# Sizeof enumerations

Tags: c++, enumeration

what is the size of an enumerated type?

```
int main()
{
enum boolean{fl,tr};
int sbool = sizeof(boolean);
boolean a=fl,b=tr;
cout<<"size of Bool Enum: "<<sbool<<endl;
enum months{jan=1,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec};
int smon = sizeof(months);
cout<<"size of months enum: "<<smon<<endl;
}
```

I had written the above code and i got sbool and smon to be 4. Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Because that's the size of a `boolean` and a reasonable integer value on your system.

Comment: The size is not specified in the language's standard. But you can use [scoped enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), and you can specify the underlying type for these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is implementation-defined which size an enumeration will have. Usually they have size equal to sizeof( int ) because in C enumerators have type int. Though even in C enumerations themselves have implementation defined compatible type. From the C Standard

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer
>   type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
>   implementation-defined

In C++ an enumeration has the size of the underlying type. You can make it fixed specifying enum-base or using of a scoped enumeration that has underlying type int if not specified otherwise.

Comment: This looks like a C++ question.

Comment: What do you mean by underlying type?

Comment: @cuba For example you may define an enumeration the following way enum Color : char { R, G, B }; Here char is the underlying type. It will be used to represent all values of the enumeration.